# "had been wanting...because I was" or "wanted...because I was"

Tags: grammar, tense

The following action is occurring in the past tense:

> It was then that it hit me: Maria **had been** wanting to commit suicide, but
>   didn’t because we rang the bell.
>
> It was then that it hit me: Maria **wanted** to commit suicide, but
>   didn’t because we rang the bell.

Which one is correct?

**EDIT:**

How about:

> It was then that it hit me: Maria **had wanted** to commit suicide, but
>   didn’t because we rang the bell.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

*Want* is a verb that describes a *state*, which means that *usually* it cannot be used in *continuous tenses*; it already describes a situation that is ongoing, so using a continuous tense is superfluous.

That is why we do not write

> *I had been wanting to do something.
>   *I am wanting to eat something.

But instead:

> I wanted to do something.
>   I want to eat something.

These kind of verbs are called *stative verbs*, and [the British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/stative-verbs) has a nice page on that subject:

> Some verbs are not usually used in the continuous form, even when we are talking about temporary situations or states. These are called stative verbs.
>   So, we say I’m sorry, I don’t understand rather than I’m not understanding.
>   **1. Stative verbs are often verbs connected with thinking and opinions.**
>   *She doesn’t know what to do NOT She isn’t knowing what to do*
>   **2. Other stative verbs are connected with feelings and emotions**
>   *I like this song. Who sings it? NOT I’m liking this song*
>   **3. ‘see’, ‘hear’, ‘taste’, ‘smell’, ‘feel’ are verbs that describe senses.**
>   These verbs aren’t usually used in continuous forms. They are often used with ‘can’.
>   *It smells of smoke in here. NOT It’s smelling of smoke in here*
>   **4. Stative verbs describe things that are not actions.**
>   Look carefully at these 2 sentences.
>   *He smells of fish.*
>   *He’s smelling the fish.*
>   The second sentence is an action – not a state. The man wants to know if the fish is OK to eat.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer to your question; the following text was written by Rachel and has been copied and formatted from [Azar Grammar Exchange website](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/7022967427)

*Regarding the **-ing form** of **'want'**, it generally does not occur, except in the **present perfect progressive** and the **past perfect progressive**:*

> Oh, thanks so much! I **'ve been wanting** the new i-Pad for a long time.
>
> Jenny **had been wanting** a Kindle since her last birthday, but when she
>   finally got one, she didn't like it; she prefers real books.